Do all regular languages have a backwards deterministic FSM with one initial state and no $\varepsilon$-transitions?
There's been a question about an algorithm converting an arbitrary FSM into a backwards deterministic automaton without $\varepsilon$-transitions and a single initial state.
As commenters pointed out, the definition of backwards determinism used wasn't standard.
So the question is

Does there exist such an automaton for all regular languages?

using the usual definition of backwards determinism:
$$\delta(p, a) \cap \delta(q, a) \neq \emptyset \Longrightarrow p = q$$
for the transition function $\delta$, states $p, q$ and character $a$.

General Idea:
I don't there is such an automaton for all regular languages.
Without $\varepsilon$-edges the amount of looping you can do is very restricted, so the idea is to show that the number of states you need to decide a word increases with its length.
Simple examples like $a^+$ and $(ab)^+$ don't work though, because the automaton can have a loop that includes the initial state.
So the counterexample I'm using is $a^+|b$, the added $|b$ should restrict the automaton from looping through the initial state.
Counterexample:
Assume, that some FSM $A$ with states $Q$ and final states $F \subseteq Q$ satisfies all three requirements (backwards determinism, $\varepsilon$-edge free, single initial state) and recognises $a^+|b$.
Then $a^n \in L(A)$ for any fixed $n > 0$, so $A$ contains states $q_0, q_1, ..., q_n$ such that
$$q_0 \overset{a}{\to} q_1 \overset{a}{\to} ... \overset{a}{\to} q_n$$
where $q_0$ is the initial state and $q_n \in F$.
Notice, that $q_0 \neq q_k$ for all $k > 0$, since otherwise
$$q_0 \overset{a}{\to} q_1 \overset{a}{\to} ... \overset{a}{\to} q_k = q_0 \overset{b}{\to} p$$
for some $p \in F$.
But this would imply $a^kb \in L(A) = a^+|b$. ↯
Assume now, that $q_j = q_k$ for some $1 \leq j < k \leq n$.
Then, due to backwards determinism
$$q_{j - 1} \overset{a}{\to} q_j \text{ and } q_{k - 1} \overset{a}{\to} q_k \Longrightarrow q_{j - 1} = q_{k - 1} \tag{1}$$
Repeating the principle in (1) we eventually get $q_0 = q_{k - j}$ where $k - j > 0$, contradicting our earlier result.
Therefore, $q_0, q_1, ..., q_n$ must be pairwise distinct.
This leads to contradiction, if $|Q| = N$ then $a^N \in L(A)$, so there is some subset $\{q_0, q_1, ..., q_N\}$ of $Q$ with cardinality $N + 1$.
Thus $A$ cannot exist.

Clean and nice solution.

Nice! Thanks for taking the time
